# in new version 4.1 release tabulator-cssClass is not working. so how to add css class into html to tabulator convert?

Tags: tabulator

I'm updating new tabulator version 4.1 HTML to tabulator tabulator-cssClass adding css class is not working.

I am trying update my tabulator and now I am getting issue to add my own css class into table header column in older version  is working but in new 4.1 version tabulator-cssClass="actionsTable hidearrow" adding css class not working. is anyone else facing same issue?

it should allow to add custom own css as before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in 4.1 that is preventing capitalized attributes from being recognised. This will be fixed for the 4.2 release at the end of the month